Run python script file on non-sql ServerA from ssis package on sql ServerB?
We have an ssis package on a sql server that uses a web service task to run a simple c# iis web service on a different non-sql server that runs a set of py files using System.Process. The py files run some ArcGIS Pro processes that output tables in a third (sql) server. We’d like to see if we can take the web service out of the mix. Can an ssis package execute a remote python file under the security context of a service account (for the local ArcGIS licensing and the sql table creation)? Thanks!
